# Criar um botão dentro de um TextBox - WPF/Mahapps

Tags: wpf

preciso criar um estilo de botão que cria uma botão dentro de um Textbox. Estou usando o WPF e uma framework chamado MahApps.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas o problema é que está ficando dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"
               x:Key="OpenFileMetroTextBox"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonCommandMetroTextBox}">
                <Setter Property="Controls:TextBoxHelper.ButtonTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Button>
                                <Rectangle Width="10" Height="10">
                                    <Rectangle.Resources>
                                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlackBrush" Color="White" />
                                    </Rectangle.Resources>
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_add}" />
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                            </Button>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

Alguém sabe como fazer?